# Entity Framework - ridiculous Query, casting smallint to int for comparison

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Out of ideas here. I have a simple table that is model first mapped with Entity Framework and I get the following SQL generated:

```
(@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 int)SELECT 
    [Extent1].[BucketRef] AS [BucketRef], 
    [Extent1].[VariantNo] AS [VariantNo], 
    [Extent1].[SliceNo] AS [SliceNo], 
    [Extent1].[TradeNo] AS [TradeNo], 
    [Extent1].[TradeBegin] AS [TradeBegin], 
    [Extent1].[TradeEnd] AS [TradeEnd], 
    FROM [simstg].[Trade] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ((( CAST( [Extent1].[BucketRef] AS int) = @p__linq__0) AND ( NOT (( CAST( [Extent1].[BucketRef] AS int) IS NULL) OR (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)))) OR (( CAST( [Extent1].[BucketRef] AS int) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND ((( CAST( [Extent1].[VariantNo] AS int) = @p__linq__1) AND ( NOT (( CAST( [Extent1].[VariantNo] AS int) IS NULL) OR (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))) OR (( CAST( [Extent1].[VariantNo] AS int) IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL)))
```

all those casts kill the perforamnce. I sadly do fail to see where they come from.

The query in question is:

```
var tradesQuery = repository.SimStgTrade
    .Where(x => x.BucketRef == bucketId && x.VariantNo == set)
    .ToArray();
```

this is as easy as it gets. The field definitions are: bucketId: short (smallint in the database), set short, smallint in the database. As such, the casts are totally not needed. I have already deleted and recreated the table in the model - and as far as I can see, the mappings match (the fields as smallint). As a result of this, we run into SERIOUS issues with performance - as in: the query times out because it does not use a table scan.

Anyone has any idea how to get rid oc those casts and force the comparison to be based on shorts? It is quite obvious from the SQL that EF decides to move everything to an int first.... which makes no sense.

This is not a "is it nice" thing. The outstanding query paths are totally different and the resulting code is turning this into a self join. In Server Manager the EF variant takes  more than 5 minutes while the optimized version with simple SQL takes 0.0 seconds (to return 228 rows out of some billion in that table).

Comment: Voting to close myself - this is similar to the issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016265/generated-query-for-tinyint-column-introduces-a-cast-to-int/9667696#9667696 - just for smallint. I won't delete it because I think it should be kept as reference. This is an easy workaround that works well enough.

Comment: Have you tried changing your model to use Int rather than Short to see if it removes the casts. In this case, any optimization you get for the smaller memory footprint is lost in the database access.

Comment: No, I have not. THe model has a short because it is a short. THe table has 10 billion entries at the moment and those 2 bytes more would result in a LOT more data. We optimized space usage for that exact reason. This is a table where half a billion rows are entered per day. We hav eno issues on other tables where the key is an int - this is particular for smallint/tinyint. And when the table is hundreds of gb then database space is quite brutal. The difference is 5 minutes 15 for 228 rows to lesss than a second. Workaround confirmed and in produciton now, as per my link.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This behavior can be common for different LINQ providers and not only EF-specific, because of how C# compiler generates expression tree for your Where expression.

When you specify condition as:

```
.Where(x => x.BucketRef == bucketId)
```

and both BucketRef and bucketId are shorts, compiler generates cast from short to int for both parts of comparison, because == operator isn't defined for Short type. This is explained in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18584429/869184

As a workaround you can rewrite condition the following way:

```
.Where(x => x.BucketRef.Equals(bucketId))
```

This effectively removes cast from comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the `Where` expression yourself using the static functions in the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Like this:

```
Int16 bucketId = 3;

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SimStgTrade));
var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "BucketRef");
var constant = Expression.Constant(bucketId);
var comparison = Expression.Equal(property, constant);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SimStgTrade,bool>>(comparison, parameter);

var tradesQuery = repository.SimStgTrade
  .Where(lambda)
  .Where(x => x.VariantNo == set)
  .ToArray();
```

Do the same for `VariantNo == set` in order to remove that cast as well

Comment: Acutally there is an easier workaround. var bucketsfilter = new [] { bucketId }; then .Where(x => bucketsfilter.Contains(x.BucketRef) - no case either. FOund it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016265/generated-query-for-tinyint-column-introduces-a-cast-to-int/9667696#9667696, same for smallint. Zero qualiy control - quite obviously.

Comment: This was very helpful to make other comparisons than Equal. Just replace Expression.Equal by Expression.GreaterThan or Expression.Less for instance. My SQL query do no longer contains the unwanted "cast" operation.